# Eclipse CDT - How to display Outline view for other file extensions

Tags: eclipse, arduino, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse for review of some Arduino code (.ino), is it possible to display this in the Outline view? The only way I have established is to rename to .cpp.

Is it possible to display a .ino file in the Outline view?

Comment: It is the editor you use that determines the outline. You can associate different content types and file extensions with an editor in the Eclipse Preferences (General > Content Types and General > Editors > File Associations)

Comment: Cool!! I went to Preferences->General->Content Types->Text-> C Source File and added "*.ino", works now. Thank you greg!